# How to fix [object Object] response from authorization which should be showing the data?

Tags: node.js, react-native, jwt, passport.js

My problem is that I am getting an empty response [object Object] when fetching the data. The response.json() is [object Object] same for just response, but with response.text() I get the req.user data in text from the protected route (passport.authenticate). The authorization goes well, it finds the user, I don't get 'Unauthorized' and in my secret route I get the user object by req.user. I only have trouble fetching this user so I can get these user values separatly, as you can do when it's JSON. Normally, response.json does the job for me, but not here. Am I missing something?

I've tried parsing data, stringify data, but they don't seem to solve it. I think I'm missing something, but I just don't see it.

```
app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.status(200).send(req.user);
    }
);

{...}
const getToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwt');
                const response = await fetch('http://ip:3000/profile', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken}`
                    }
                });
                const data = await response;
                console.log('Response: ' + data);
{...}
```

Expected results is for the response in the fetch to show the user, or basically have .json show the user. But instead of showing the user it gives [object Object].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should JSON.stringify the response

```
console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Honestly, I tried this, but I guess I messed something up when trying this. So I stringifyd data, made response.json() and I can access the user data! Thanks for your anwser, this gets me further :)

Answer (score 1):

The `object-object` output comes when the output is not parsed or if it is nested inside so the parser can't read that.

To solve that problem you have to convert the output into string and then show them.

There are probably two ways :

`1. console.log('data',JSON.Stringify(data));`

`2. console.log('data',data.toString())`

Answer (score 0):

Simpler, pass `data` as second parameter.

```
console.log('Response: ', data);
```

Comment: Maybe simpler, but that's really preference, isn't it? I prefer to do it with + so I can see in the code okay this belongs to this and that it's not separated.